# I am facing issue while calling withdraw function from react

Tags: solidity, contract-development, dapps, dapp-development, react

I have a withdraw function in solidity script:

```
function withdraw() public onlyOwner {
        (bool sent, ) = owner.call{value: 0.00025 ether}("");
        require(sent);
    }
```

Technically it should not allow any user except owner to call it, but i have an issue, this is my react script to call this from fron-end:

```
import React from "react"
//import { ethers } from "ethers"

function WithdrawFund({ contract, signer, advisor }) {
    async function handleWithdraw() {
        await contract.withdraw({ gasLimit: 200000 })
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <button
                className="px-4 py-1 text-xl text-purple-600 font-semibold rounded-xl border border-purple-200 hover:text-white hover:bg-purple-600 hover:border-transparent focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-purple-600 focus:ring-offset-2"
                onClick={handleWithdraw}
            >
                Withdraw
            </button>
        </div>
    )
}

export default WithdrawFund
```

As far as my solidity code is considered it should not allow any other user to call it except owner but this is not happening, i can call it with any user and i am receiving no error. Where i am doing wrong??

Answer (score 0):

You are not specifying the `from`, only the `gasLimit`. The sender (`from` in the parameters) must be the owner of the contract, which somehow is set as the default account being used.

Try using the following instead:

```js
await contract.connect(signer).withdraw({ gasLimit: 200000 })
```

Just so you know, the `.connect(<signer>)` method will recreate the same contract object in Javascript, but setting the default signer as the one being provided, which will cause any transaction to have the `msg.sender` in Solidity as the address behind that signer.